# How to pass an xbbg/blpapi Bloomberg time series into a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, bloomberg, blpapi

I am using xbbg and blpapi to pull time series directly from Bloomberg and would like to turn them into a pandas DataFrame to be able to run some time series analysis.
I would really appreciate any suggestions as I am a very novice user.
My code is as follows:

I am stuck with how to pass the blp output into a pandas DataFrame! Thank you so much.

```
#Import Bloomberg API
import blpapi as BBG
#Import xbbg
from xbbg import blp
#Import pandas
import pandas as pd
#Pull monthly price time series
blp.bdh(
tickers='SPX Index', flds=['Last_Price','EQY_FUND_CRNCY=CAD'],
start_date='2020-12-31', end_date='2021-05-31',
Per='M',
)
#?Now how to pass into pandas DataFrame???
```

Comment: I have a single file wrapper that is, I think, simpler than xbbg and should achieve what you want https://github.com/alex314159/blpapiwrapper

Comment: @ alex314159 - Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I don't have administrator rights and cannot download new libraries. It took me a couple weeks just to get IT approval for blpapi, xbbg, numpy and pandas. I was hoping to find a solution using what I have.

Comment: Doesn’t blp.bdh() return a DataFrame already? `df=blp.bdh(...)` then `print(type(df))`

Answer (score 1):

The blp.bdh() function already returns a DataFrame containing the results. There is no additional processing needed:

```
from xbbg import blp

#Pull monthly price time series
df = blp.bdh(tickers='SPX Index', flds=['Last_Price','EQY_FUND_CRNCY=CAD'],
             start_date='2020-12-31', end_date='2021-05-31',Per='M')

print(df)
```

yields:

```
    SPX Index
           Last_Price
2020-12-31    3756.07
2021-01-29    3714.24
2021-02-26    3811.15
2021-03-31    3972.89
2021-04-30    4181.17
2021-05-31    4204.11
```